# Difference between forwardRef and ComponentPropsWithRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add ref to my custom function component. What is the difference between forwardRef and ComponentPropsWithRef?

`const MyComponent = (ref) => { return <div ref={ref}>Some text</div> }`

I have tried to use ComponentPropsWithRef but it doesn't add ref at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ref.current` without `React.forwardRef` will always be whatever initial value was passed to `useRef` and won't change.
`React.ComponentPropsWithRef` only adds `ref` property to the props of the component. 
The solution might be `const MyComponent= forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, MyComponentProps>((ref, props) => {return <div ref={ref}>Some text</div>})`

Comment: Thank you kindly! That works and im able to put a ref on my component!